# Wrap xuggler inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, xuggler

I am unable to find any post that clearly demonstrates how to wrap Xuggler within a JPanel. I can see some posts for JFrame though, but the solution doesn't easily translate to JPanel. (Or maybe I am too naive!)

To be more specific, the following method does not work for JPanel as it does for JFrame -

```
private class MyVideoFrame extends JFrame
{
  ....
  public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      if (image != null)
      {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would a JPanel work like a JFrame, and why would you do **that**?

Comment: Don't override `paint`, do call `super.paintXxx`...

Comment: Based on [this official example](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayVideo.java), Xuggler is can provide you with a BufferedImage, which simply needs to be painted. Havn't tried, don't have the library, but failing to understand why you're having problems?

Answer (score 1):

The [`VideoImage`](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/VideoImage.java) source actually uses `JComponent`, which is not the best choice, but is the parent to `JPanel`.

The fact they've overridden `paint` and failed to call `super.paint` is a really bad example.

Instead, they should have used a `JPanel` (it's not transparent by default), overridden `paintComponent` and called `super.paintComponent` before rendering the frame.

So based on [DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo.java) or [DecodeAndPlayVideo](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayVideo.java)

You should be able to replace the reference to `com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.VideoImage` with the one below, which uses a `JPanel` as the main container for the vide frame container for displaing...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VideoImage extends JFrame {

    private final ImagePane mOnscreenPicture;

    public VideoImage() {
        super();
        mOnscreenPicture = new ImagePane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(mOnscreenPicture);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void setImage(final BufferedImage aImage) {
        mOnscreenPicture.setImage(aImage);
    }

    //....Inner class here....//

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage mImage;

        public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageRunnable(image));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return mImage == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
        }

        private class ImageRunnable implements Runnable {

            private final BufferedImage newImage;

            public ImageRunnable(BufferedImage newImage) {
                super();
                this.newImage = newImage;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImagePane.this.mImage = newImage;
                Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
                final Dimension newSize = new Dimension(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
                if (!newSize.equals(size)) {
                    VideoImage.this.invalidate();
                    VideoImage.this.revalidate();
                    VideoImage.this.pack();
                    repaint();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public ImagePane() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (mImage != null) {
                g.drawImage(mImage, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```